# Pytchat is not fetching live chat from youtube

Tags: python

```py
from pytchat import LiveChat
import time
chat = LiveChat(video_id = "uIx8l2xlYVY")

while chat.is_alive():
  try:
    data = chat.get()
    items = data.items
    for c in items:
        print(f"{c.datetime} [{c.author.name}]- {c.message}")
    time.sleep(3)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    chat.terminate()
    break
```

Can anyone please explain why it is not fetching YouTube live chat even video ID is changed multiple times.

Comment: What's the error. Or what is it outputting and what would you like it to output?

Comment: Blank output nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix:

```py
import pytchat
import time
chat = pytchat.create(video_id="uIx8l2xlYVY")
while chat.is_alive():
  try:
    for c in chat.get().sync_items():
        print(f"{c.datetime} [{c.author.name}]- {c.message}")
    time.sleep(3)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    chat.terminate()
    break
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I tried with multiple ID....which are live on YouTube now.... nothing happens.

Comment: I think I found your issue let me edit my response.

Comment: Okay I will try..

Comment: Hey I edited my answer one more time and this should be the fix!

Comment: Still not working it fails to fetch YouTube Live chats

Comment: @TONY why did you say it was correct wait 2 days then unmark it

Answer (score 0):

[pytchat](https://github.com/taizan-hokuto/pytchat) is no more maintained, [chat-downloader](https://github.com/xenova/chat-downloader) - use this library instead, it works